# javascript remove event in handler,

Tags: javascript, events, mousemove

please have a look at http://jsbin.com/nubeb/1/edit

```
(function(){
  var func = function(e){
    console.log("mouse move");
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove",func);
  };
  document.addEventListener("mousemove",func);
  console.log("working");
}());
```

i want to know that,Is it possible to replace 'func' from

```
document.removeEventListener("mousemove",func);
```

to some other keyword, i want to write it like below code

```
(function(){
  document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove",***);
  });
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have 2 different option, here the first one is using `arguments.callee` which is gonna be deprecated in the near future, using `arguments.callee` we have access to the current function which is being executed, so you can do something like this:

```
(function(){
   document.addEventListener("mousemove",function mylistener(e){
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", arguments.callee);
   });
}());
```

> Warning: The 5th edition of ECMAScript (ES5) forbids use of
>   arguments.callee() in strict mode.

Read this for more info: [arguments.callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee)

As you see, other than getting deprecated in the near future, you can not use `arguments.callee`, in the `strict mode` which can bring us some trouble.

We have a new alternative, which can help us not use `arguments.callee`. Ok let's say we have a function like this:

```
var myfunc = function yourfunc(){
    //yourfunc is accessible
};
//but here yourfunc is not accessible
```

In this code, we can use `yourfunc` only in the function body but out of that context we only have `myfunc`. It sounds like we kind of have a private pointer in the scope of the function which is accessible and can be used instead of `arguments.callee`.

So this is the new alternative which can be also used in `strict mode`, so in your code you can do this like:

```
(function(){
   document.addEventListener("mousemove",function mylistener(e){
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mylistener);
   });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code http://jsbin.com/wopitiba/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
(function(){

     document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
       console.log("mouse move");
       document.removeEventListener("mousemove",arguments.callee);
     });
     console.log("working");
}());
```